# How to add a preview image to Navigator.share()

Tags: javascript, web

I'm currently using `Navigator.share()` to invoke the `native share API`. Everything is fine and dandy except what I'm sharing is a `link to an image`.

On `iOS`, there is a `preview image` that shows up when using `Safari's share icon` and I can't figure out how to get that to show up for `Navigator.share()` as well.

[Navigator.share()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhj4u.jpg)

Here is an example of the same page being shared using `Safari's browse share tool`.

[Safari's browser share tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG170.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I came across a solution.

The data `Navigator.share()` is expecting can contain the properties: `title`, `text`, `url`, and `files`. I only use `title`, `text`, and `url`. I decided to omit `title` and `text` and it worked! I'm guessing it's because when they are set, the API doesn't use the meta information provided by the page to produce the preview image.

Comment: Hi, where can you see the preview, at least Chrome under Win11 does not show it?